# Using 'this' as a function in Javascript apply

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
    Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    let f = this
    return function(...args) {
        setTimeout(()=>this.apply(this, args), ms); //**
    }
};


function f(a, b) {
  alert( a + b );
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second
```

So the above code gives an error saying "this.apply is not a function". However, if I change the line with (**) to

```
setTimeout(()=>f.apply(this, args), ms);
```

the code runs fine, even though f still references "this". What gives?

Comment: But it's not the same _"this"_. Just check its content.

Comment: the `this` you are referencing gives reference to global object `this` inside setTimeout function, but when you are storing `this` in local variable `f` that `f` is pointing to the `this` of the function and not the global object `this`

Comment: The ‘this’ keyword in JS can be a little tricky at times. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at the code provided in the question to see why one works and
the other doesn't.

Let's first take a look at the functioning example:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function (ms) {
  let f = this;
  return function(...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms);
  };
};

function f(a, b) {
  alert(a + b);
}
```

```
f.defer(1000)(1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second
// translates to
setTimeout(() => f.appy(this, [1, 2]), 1000);
//                       ^
// here `this` refers to the global object (window)
```

Let's have a look at the non-working example:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function (ms) {
  return function(...args) {
    setTimeout(() => this.apply(this, args), ms);
  };
};

function f(a, b) {
  alert(a + b);
}
```

```
f.defer(1000)(1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second
// translates to
setTimeout(() => this.appy(this, [1, 2]), 1000);
//                ^         ^
// here `this` refers to the global object (window)
```

Since `this` in the above context points to the global object (window) you could
also write this as:

```
setTimeout(() => window.appy(window, [1, 2]), 1000);
```

Since `window` is an object and not a function this explains the error you're
getting.

Comment: Like others already pointed out every `function () { ... }` body introduces a new `this` binding. `this` in `defer` points the receiver (`f` in `f.defer(1000)`). The anonymous function returned by `defer` is called without receiver thus `this` will point to the global object.

Answer (score 1):

Every `function` has it's own `this`, which is not necessary identical with the outer `this`.

You could bind [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) to the returned function for the parameters.

Inside of this function `this` stays, because you take an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), where the outer `this` is taken.

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    return function(...args) {
        setTimeout(() => this.apply(this, args), ms); //**
    }.bind(this);
};

function f(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second
```

Comment: How about adding an explanation on the actual problem so TO understands why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

the function's `this` would change, just like when you have the same parameter name (`ms` in the following example) as outer scope.

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
    let f = this
    return function(ms,...args) {
        setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms); //**
    }
};

function f(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}

f.defer(100000)(1000, 1, 2); // shows 3 after 1 second (not 100 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of *this* is different between arrow functions and regular functions. For arrow functions they each have their own *this*.

But when *this* is used in other functions there is a more complex set of rules, and often it depends on where the function is called from. Here's a list of those rules, if you're interested: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#review-tldr